# Facebook - share post from website

Tags: facebook, post, authentication, share, facebook-group

I ask for something special because I couldn't find some good and helpful answer for me.

I have one project, which uses Facebook API Login. It means that user for registration need to have Facebook account. For this project, I'd like to make one function now, which will works following:

1/ Somebody can add some new item.
2/ After fill in form and click send button, form is executed, validating and everything is saved into database. If this process is successful so to one specific Facebook group is added post about new item and maybe (I will see yet) also is added post on wall user's Facebook account.

My question is: 
Is it possible or not? And if yes, so how I can do this?

Comment: autoposting to user profiles is not allowed, and you can only publish to groups you manage. about how to do stuff with the api: please start reading the official docs and the api reference, there is example code and a lot of information to start programming right away. questions like "is xy possible" and "how can i do xy" are way too broad for stackoverflow, you have to do some research and testing first.

Comment: so super! thanks a lot. have a nice day

Comment: and can you tell me at least name of this api? I was looking for some phrases for this functions but without successful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is called "graph api"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/